# React - arrow function syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

Long story short when working in React, there are situations when I have to use arrow functions with `()` instead of `{}` and vice-versa.

```
const foo = (item) => ( ... );
```

and

```
const foo = (item) => { ... };
```

My code is often failing because I am confusing them. What, I am trying to understand is the difference between the two arrow functions. What are the best-case scenarios for both?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow function *without* curly braces return the function expression. Example:

```
() => 'Hello world';
```

will do the same as

```
function() {
  return 'Hello world';
}
```

If you use curly braces, you can add multiple statements. Example:

```
() => {
  const str = 'Hello world';
  return str;
}
```

will do the same as:

```
function() {
  const str = 'Hello world';
  return str;
}
```

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more details.

**Some little extra notes:**

Because of the syntax rules, when you want to return an object in an arrow function, you'll have to wrap it in braces:

```
() => ({
  key: 'value',
  another_key: 'another_value'
});
```

The main differences between `function()` and `() => ...` are that arrow functions don't have bindings to some keywords (like `this`) and that arrow functions *don't* have a prototype and can't be used as constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether I understand you correctly, but:

```
const oneLiner = (param) => myArr.filter().map();

const twoLiner = (param) => {func1(); func2();}
```

If you can put everything in one line (like mapping or filtering) you dont need any parentheses for the body of your function. If you need more than one line, use {}.

Also, the oneLiner returns a value, even without "return". The second function does need the keyword "return" to return something.